# prevProps.search.query is always the same as this.props.search.query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

`prevProps.search.query` is always the same as `this.props.search.query` after dispatching action to update redux state.

If I type 'testing' in the input and log `this.props.search.query` and `prevProps.search.query` in `componentDidUpdate()` they will both print 'testing'

Shouldn't `prevProps.search.query` be `testin` (without the h as it was the prev search query)?

```
// results component

class Results extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      resultsClass: 'row search-results',
      results: null,
      searchQuery: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){

    if(this.props.search.query !== prevProps.search.query){
      this.getSearchResults();
    }

  }

}

// input component

<input type="text" onChange={this.handleSearchUpdate} />

handleSearchUpdate() {

  this.props.dispatch(setSearchQuery(this.queryInput.value));

}
```

In my reducers, I am setting the state

```
case constants.SET_SEARCH_QUERY:
        return merge({}, set(state, 'search.query', action.query));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u mistaken it with componentWillReceiveProps.
You should use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`, if you need `nextProps`

learn more here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: ComponentDidUpdate also has nextProps - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: yeap, you are right, it works should work well even with `didUpdate` just tested on my input. I think you better show whole component, maybe problem is in render section.